# Is there a more casual way of saying "beyond reproach, criticism"?

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a more casual way of saying "beyond reproach, criticism"? When I hear "beyond reproach", I find it that it sounds way too formal, and not too informal enough. It sounds like something a British actor would say, but it doesn't sound great if you speak with friends. Is there a way more casual way of putting it?

Comment: What context would this be in? Referring to a person? Meant earnestly or with a little bit of sarcasm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(All definitions below are from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary.)

For starters, there's [irreproachable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irreproachable):

> not reproachable : BLAMELESS, IMPECCABLE

There's also [unimpeachable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unimpeachable):

> : not impeachable: such as
>
> : reliable beyond a doubt
>
> : not liable to accusation

If those are still too formal, perhaps [untouchable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/untouchable):

> : exempt from criticism or control

Comment: I'm not sure about "untouchable" but the others are good.  The problem is that they're at least as formal as "beyond reproach", and perhaps not really the answer blackbird is hoping for.